# How to determine if a device is SATA driven and will be affect by the Sandy Bridge Intel Issue?

Tags: usb, sata, intel-core-i7

Looking to buy a higher-end Windows 7 laptop, but I'm concerned about the issue with the Intel Sandy Bridge chipset. Otherwise, my price range covers laptops within the latest (Sandy Bridge) generation of the Core i7 family.

I understand that there is an [issue with SATA ports 2-5](https://superuser.com/questions/241779/after-intels-admission-should-sandy-bridge-processors-be-used) and I use a Windows Home Server over a WiFi connection to share files and backup my PC (transfers probably average 3gb per day between these two devices). The other storage devices that I will use (less frequently) are the built-in DVD-RW disc drive and various devices hooked up to the USB ports (i.e. Android devices, iPod, etc.). The question: **Will this setup be negatively impacted by [the problem Intel reported](http://www.intel.com/consumer/products/processors/chipset.htm) about Sandy Bridge? Given this information, is it unwise to purchase a laptop that has this flaw?**

I really don't know how to determine whether a device is SATA driven or not, so hoping someone can shed some light on this too. Thanks!

Comment: Just an FYI: It seems that this issue has been resolved. Am having a 2nd generation i7 laptop shipped on 4/7/11. Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtually all *normal* drives bought now are SATA drives, so yes, it is possible for the Sandy Bridge issue to affect the speed of your storage.

But I would contact the vendor you want to buy your laptop from and ask them when it's 'safe' to buy a Sandy Bridge-based laptop.  You might need to dig through their layers of sales reps to get to a manager who knows what they are talking about, but they should be able to give you a pretty specific time frame on when the updated Sandy Bridge-based laptops will ship.

They might even be willing to sell you a 'faulty' laptop and guarantee to swap it out when the new versions become available. But I wouldn't count on it.

Answer (score 1):

All reputable dealers have stopped selling PCs that are affected by the Sandy Bridge problem.

You could either wait for the problem to be resolved, or buy a somewhat older model.

Comment: Will be late April or early March before the revised Cougar Point chip is available for sale in products.